# Bash script using SED and nextline

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have two files, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. I want to use `sed` and read line in a bash script. I want to replace row 1 **user** in `file1.txt` with row 1 from `file2.txt` and so on...

file1.txt:

```
xxxx1 <br>
xxxx2 <br>
xxxx3
```

file2.txt:

```
{"Something":null,"ID":"user","group":{"id":"group1") <br>
{"Something":null,"ID":"user","group":{"id":"group1") <br>
{"Something":null,"ID":"user","group":{"id":"group1")
```

New file2.txt should be like this:

```
{"Something":null,"ID":"xxxx1","group":{"id":"group1") <br>
{"Something":null,"ID":"xxxx2","group":{"id":"group1") <br>
{"Something":null,"ID":"xxxx3","group":{"id":"group1")
```

Any good ideas?

Comment: That's a nice set of requirements you have there. What part of it are you stuck on? Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: Would be trivial in `awk`.

Comment: Maybe awk is better to go for, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It is easy using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { user[FNR] = $1; next } { sub("user", user[FNR]); print }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

However, you could also do it using `paste` and `sed`:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | sed -r 's/([^ ]+)([^{]+)(\{.*)user(.*)/\3\1\4/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below command :

```
 for data in `awk '{print NR":"$1}' file1.txt` ; do row=`cut -d":" -f1 <<< ${data}` ;user=`cut -d":" -f2 <<< ${data}` ;sed -i ''$row's/"user",/"'$user'",/g' file2.txt ; done
```

Comment: This is an extremely inefficient loop. A single `awk` invocation could do all the work.